# Is there any way to replace a vertex in a graph by a triangle?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

In the picture below, I would like to create the graph on the right from the graph on the left.
[image]
The graph on the left is easy to code.

```
G = PlanarGraph[{v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10},
{v1<->v2, v1<->v5, v1<->v7,v2<->v3,Labeled[v2<->v8, "e"], v3<->v9, v3<->v4, v4<->v10, v4<->v5, Labeled[v5<->v6, "e'"], v6<->v7, v7<->v8, v8<->v9, v9<->v10, v10<->v6}]
```

Let's say that $v_1$ is the left vertex incident with edge $e$ and that $v_2$ is the right vertex incident with $e'$. Is there any way to replace both $v_1$ and $v_2$ with triangles?

I would appreciate any help. I am new to coding in Mathematica.

Comment: See `VertexAdd` and `EdgeAdd`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** A function that adds new vertices and edges incident to a given vertex:

```
ClearAll[vReplace]
vReplace = Module[{ne, g = EdgeDelete[#, IncidenceList[#, #2]], 
     nv = Append[Table[Symbol["v" <> ToString@#2 <> x],
       {x, Take[CharacterRange["a", "z"], VertexDegree[#, #2] - 1]}], #2]}, 
  ne = Join[MapThread[ReplaceAll, {IncidenceList[#, #2], Thread[#2 -> nv]}], 
     UndirectedEdge @@@ Partition[nv, 2, 1, 1]]; 
  GraphUnion[g, ne, ##3]] &;
```

Note: We can replace `Graphunion[...]` with `Graph[EdgeAdd[VertexAdd[g, nv], ne], ##3]` in the last line to get the same result.

***Examples:***

```
vReplace[G, v2, Options @ G]
```

[image]

```
HighlightGraph[vReplace[G, v2, VertexSize -> Large, VertexStyle -> White, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
  EdgeStyle -> Directive[CapForm["Round"], AbsoluteThickness[15]]], 
 Complement[EdgeList[vReplace[G, v2]], EdgeList[G]]]
```

[image]

```
Fold[vReplace, G, {v2, v5}]
```

[image]

```
Fold[vReplace, G, {v1, v2, v3, v4, v5}]
```

[image]

Replace every vertex with a *triangle*:

```
Fold[vReplace, G, VertexList[G]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
G = PlanarGraph[{v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10}, 
     {v1 <-> v2, v1 <-> v5, v1 <-> v7, v2 <-> v3, Labeled[v2 <-> v8, "e"], 
     v3 <-> v9, v3 <-> v4, v4 <-> v10, v4 <-> v5, Labeled[v5 <-> v6, "e'"], v6 <-> v7, 
     v7 <-> v8, v8 <-> v9, v9 <-> v10, v10 <-> v6}, 
     VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

[image]

```
G2 = Graph[EdgeDelete[G, Join[IncidenceList[G, v2], IncidenceList[G, v5]]], 
  VertexCoordinates -> GraphEmbedding[G]]
```

[image]

```
newvertices = {v2a, v2b, v5a, v5b}; 

newedges = Flatten @ {
    MapThread[ReplaceAll, {IncidenceList[G, v2], {v2 -> v2a, v2 -> v2b, v2 -> v2}}], 
    MapThread[ReplaceAll, {IncidenceList[G, v5], {v5 -> v5a, v5 -> v5b, v5 -> v5}}],
    v2 <-> # & /@ {v2a, v2b}, v5 <-> # & /@ {v5a, v5b},
    v2a <-> v2b, v5a <-> v5b};

EdgeAdd[VertexAdd[G2, newvertices], newedges]
```

[image]

Comment: What’s the minimum number of vertices & edges you need to start from? Can you use just a set of 3 vertices and 3 edges? I.e., a triangle?

Comment: @CATrevillian, if the vertex to be replaced has `VertexDegree` `k` it is _replaced with `k` vertices and `k` edges. For example,  try `vReplace[CompleteKaryTree[3, 6, VertexLabels -> "Name"], 1,  VertexLabels -> "Name"]`. (The ordering of the new vertices needs further work to preserve planarity.)